# How to checkout and edit pull request branch made from fork which is deleted?

Tags: git, github

I had made pull request from fork, but then I deleted fork. How can I mend this pull request now? I tried finding my branch in upstream branches when using fork but it isn't there.

Comment: You can't (amend the PR). You *can* get the commits and make a new and *different* PR, from a new fork, but since your old fork is *gone* you can't *fix* the old PR.

Answer (score 0):

check commits and commit ID and then try to git checkout commitID

Comment: could you add commands which I need to execute? I'm not sure how can I check it out. As I get you I used git checkout commithash but have this error fatal: reference is not a tree: commithash

Comment: and I've tried this on cloned base repo

Comment: Just go in repo and check there IDs of each commit...

Comment: As I said I have error with this

Comment: this works only if branch is there in base repo. but it exists there only as pull request.